# How do I parse this piece of XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

I have the following piece of XML in my SQL:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BillingAddresses>
  <BillingAddress Winner="W1">
    <Losers>
      <Loser Id="L1" />
      <Loser Id="L2" />
      <Loser Id="L3" />
    </Losers>
  </BillingAddress>
  <BillingAddress Winner="W10">
    <Losers>
      <Loser Id="L65" />
    </Losers>
  </BillingAddress>
</BillingAddresses>'
```

I'd like to fetch data in the following manner.

```
Winner | LoserID 
W1       L1
W1       L2
W1       L3
W10      L65
```

I can get to the Winner attribute of BillingAddress:

```
SELECT Col.value('(@Winner)[1]', 'varchar(30)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/BillingAddresses/BillingAddress') Rev(Col)
```

but I am at a loss how to get to the Id attribute of the Loser nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it...

```
    SELECT 
         Col.value('(../../@Winner)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS WinnerId
        ,Col.value('(@Id)[1]', 'varchar(18)') AS LoserId
    FROM @xml.nodes('/BillingAddresses/BillingAddress/Losers/Loser') Rev(Col)
```

The trick is to go as deep into the XML hierarchy, then use the relative operator (../) to make your way out to fetch whatever parent piece you need.